# Как в typescript исключить из сборки кусок кода?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, typescript

Я разрабатываю модули на typescript.
К примеру у меня есть два модуля:

- **my-module-1**
- **my-module-2**

в **my-module-1** имеется такой код:

```
import { AnyLibrary } from "anylibrary";

export class MyApplication {
    private readonly _lib: AnyLibrary;

    constructor() {
        this._lib = new AnyLibrary();
    }

    update() {
         this._lib.doSomething();
    }
}
```

**my-module-2** в зависимостях использует **my-module-1**

Эти два модуля опубликованы в npm репозитории.

Я создаю проект **my-project** и подключаю зависимость **my-module-2**.
Теперь при сборки **my-project** я хочу сделать так, чтобы AnyLibrary из **my-module-1** не попала в билд и код с работой с ней соответственно.
Это вообще возможно?

### Зачем это нужно

Нужно для того, чтобы уменьшить вес финального билда, а библиотека **AnyLibrary** используется только для разработки, к примеру для вывода на экран debug информации.

Раньше я писал на javascript и использовал webpack для сборки проекта. Там я использовал loader: `webpack-preprocessor-loader`, что позволяло использовать директивы препроцессора и я мог добавлять проверки вида: `//#!if //#!else //#!endif` и при сборке менять переменную для *develop* и для *production*.

Но тут кроме того, что нет поддержки директив препроцессора, так ещё и отдельными модулями, не думаю что я смогу как-то передать при сборке **my-project** используемому модулю **my-module-2** параметр о том, что сборка для production и поэтому убери **AnyLibrary** и упоминание её в финальной сборке.

Что посоветуете?

Comment: Документация webpack-preprocessor-loader намекает, что он вполне поддерживает typescript. У вас какие-то проблемы с ним или вы просто решили зачем-то полностью отказаться от webpack?

Comment: Если я правильно помню, компилятор typescript вообще не занимается сборкой кода

Comment: @andreymal да, я отказался от webpack в пользу vite.js

Comment: @AlexeyTen почему? команда tsc как раз делает то, что собирает проект

Comment: tsc компилирует файлы. Из одного исходного файла получается один скомпилированный. Сборкой всей этой толпы в один готовый файл занимается, например, webpack (или кто-то ещё).

Comment: Вообще, если у вас вот такой код, то непонятно как вы собираетесь избавляться от AnyLibrary, она же используется в рантайме. Так же интересно что именно публикуется в npm. Исходные ts-файлы или скомпилированный JS или какой-то ещё вариант?